# Updating record value with dropdown adding value to "undefined" data element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui

I am working on a Location edit form that has and API populated dropdown list of Departments.  I am using the record's departmentId to select the current value in the dropdown.  The problem arises when I select a new department, the ID is being written to a new data element called 'undefined', like this:

```json
    values: 
       id: 1
       name: "Location1"
       description: "Plating"
       isArchived: 0,
       departmentId: 18
       undefined: 22
```

Could someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

**Dropdown as inside form & API Call**

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
     const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`${editUrl + (selectedRecord.id)}`);
        setValues( res.data );
      };
      fetchData();
    }, []); 


      <Controls.Dropdown
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            label='Department'
            name='departmentId'
            value={values.departmentId}
            prompt='Select A Department...'
            url='/api/maintain/departments/'
      />
```

**onChange Event** (handles all values of the form)

```
    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
            // [name]: value
             [name]: ( typeof value === 'string' ? (value).replace(/ +(?= )/g, '').trimStart() : value )
        });
        if (validateOnChange)
          { validate({ [name]: value }); }
    };
```

**Dropdown Component**

```
export default function Dropdown(props) {
  const { error = null, label, name, onChange, prompt, value, url, ...other } = props;
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
  const dropdownUrl = environment.originURL + environment.apiUrl + url; 


// Fetch Data for Dropdown list
  React.useEffect(() => {
       const fetchData = async () => {
         const res = await axios.get(dropdownUrl);
         setOptions( res.data.sort((a, b) => (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1) ); // values sorted by name case-insensitive
       };
       fetchData();
   }, []); 


  return(
    <FormControl>
        <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
        <Select
                defaultValue=''
                onChange={onChange}
                value={(value === undefined || value === null || options.length === 0) ? '' : value}
                name={name}
                {...other}
                {...(error && {error: true, helperText: error})}
            >
            <MenuItem value=''>{prompt}</MenuItem>
            {options.map((option, id) => (
                <MenuItem
                    key={option.id}
                    value={option.id}
                >
                    {option.name}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Select>
    </FormControl>
    );
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to set a `name` for `Select`? It seems like your `onChange` handler uses `e.target.name` and it's `undefined`

Comment: @Danila  You nailed it!  I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: The code had been updated with the suggestion and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onChange` handler uses `e.target.name` as a key but it seems that your `Select` (or `Controls.Dropdown`) does not have it as a prop. So just pass a name prop to it:

```
<Controls.Dropdown
            // Add name here for example
            name="department"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            label='Department'
            name='departmentId'
            value={values.departmentId}
            prompt='Select A Department...'
            url='/api/maintain/departments/'
      />
```